# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object error - Error al mover una carpeta en mi código

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Tengo este código (que no es mío) y estoy resolviendo errores que surgieron. Básicamente tengo un folder denominado Root, este folder aparece por defecto en mi programa, no se puede eliminar ni mover; dentro de este folder puedo crear más folders que puedo eliminar o mover. Estoy tratando de resolver el siguiente problema que aparece cuando trato de pegar un folder en la carpeta Root.

Dentro de frmMain.cs mando a llamar una funcion llamada **CopyTestCaseFolder** que está en **MainManager.cs**, pero en `targetFolder.id` me lanza este error que menciono a continuación.

Aquí les dejo mi código en c#

frmMain.cs

```
private void pasteTestCaseRootFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_mainManager.TestCaseFolderToCopy != null && trvTestCases.SelectedNode != null)
            {
        
                if (trvTestCases.SelectedNode.Tag == null) // is root
                {
                    _mainManager.CopyTestCaseFolder(null, moveEntity);
                }

                pasteTestCaseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                pasteTestCaseRootFolderToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                RefreshTestCaseTab();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pasteTestCaseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            pasteTestCaseRootFolderToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            RefreshTestCaseTab();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Paste Test Case folder - Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

MainManager.cs

```
public void CopyTestCaseFolder(TestFolder targetFolder, bool move)
    {
        
        _testCaseLogic.isFirstFolderCopied = false;
        if (TestCaseFolderToCopy.FolderId == targetFolder.Id) //justamente aqui tengo el error 
        {
            _testCaseLogic.CopyFolderToSameFolder(TestCaseFolderToCopy);
            TestCaseFolderToCopy = _testCaseLogic.firstFolderCopy;
        }
        else
        {
            if (move)
            {
                MoveTestFolder(TestCaseFolderToCopy, targetFolder);
            }
            else
            {
                _testCaseLogic.CopyFolderToAnotherFolder(TestCaseFolderToCopy, targetFolder.Id);
                TestCaseFolderToCopy = _testCaseLogic.firstFolderCopy;
            }
        }
        if (targetFolder.QTestFolderId != null && !move)
        {
            frmQtestProgress qtestProgress = new frmQtestProgress(_qTestManager);
            qtestProgress.SetLinkTestFolderToQTestModule_AddOrCopyValues(TestCaseFolderToCopy, targetFolder,true);
            qtestProgress.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

TestFolder.cs

```
 public class TestFolder : ComponentEntity
{
    public TestFolder()
    {
        TestCases = new List<TestCase>();
        Folders = new List<TestFolder>();
    }

    public int TempId { get; set; }
    public string Children { get; set; }
    public GherkinFile GherkinFile { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<TestCase> TestCases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestFolder> Folders { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? FolderId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public TestFolder Folder { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public long? QTestFolderId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string QTestFolderPID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string QTestFolderName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Parece que la clase TestCaseFolderToCopy no esta siendo inicializada, me gustaría ver esa clase.

Comment: Si esta inicializada de la siguiente manera

`public TestFolder TestCaseFolderToCopy { get; set; }`

Encontre que el error esta en **targetFolder**,  se lo esta pasando como null en **frmMain.cs**, y cuando hace el comparativo dentro del if, sale error porque si esta null, no tiene un **.id**